# What determined which companies went to which post-Soviet republics after the fall of the Soviet Union as everything was centralized in Moscow?

Tags: ukraine, soviet-union

After the fall of the Soviet Union, all the post-Soviet republics (e.g., Ukraine, Kazakhstan) inherited some state-owned corporations. However, since all the corporations were under the control of the central government in Moscow despite having had operations in republics other than the Russian soviet socialist republic, what determined which corporations and enterprises were given to which republic?

Comment: There was no Russian SSR, only a Russian SFSR

Comment: It's quite straighforward to just give out production assets according to their physical location, isn't it? Kiev aircraft plant to Ukraine, Tiflis aircraft plant to Georgia etc.

Comment: I've a vague recolection of the USSR, in the late '80s, complaining that independence for the Baltic states would leave them out of pocket because most of the infrastructure investment had been provided by the Kremlin.  Not sure how to search for news articles that far back.

Comment: @Jan yes, and that's largely what happened. Though the Russians did try to truck and fly anything that wasn't bolted down back home. Which is part of the reason for the resentment against them by many of the other former Soviet republics.

Comment: @Jan that's true, although this is more or less the reason why I asked. Since technically the Moscow government was in control of it all, under what laws or pre-established framework would they give those geographic regions the corresponding industries? If this was to be done by a vote wouldn't the Russian federation get most of the control (since they are bigger and would have more representation in the soviet system)

Comment: @Schwarz Kugelblitz: That's not how independence works. If some area gets Independent, it takes those state-owned assets that can be brought under its control with it. Both because it can and because it has the right to do so. "The Uzbek rail network was the property of the whole Soviet people, but now it is only the property of the Russian people" is not going to work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Corporations and plants were divided between republics according to their geographical location. Under Soviet Union they were in some sense "controlled by Moscow government" but not directly. Republics also had their governments and control organs. Each republic had its own supreme control organ called (republican) [Gosplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DerzhPlan), and ministries for various branches of industry. And there was also central [all-union Gosplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosplan) in Moscow. Some enterprises (a minority) were controlled
from Moscow directly, but most by republican governments. But there was no question to whom
a specific plant belongs after separation: the plants went to the republics where they were located. Control organs had to be reorganized, and in many republics, many plants were privatized.

Several facilities on the territories of former soviet republics were leased to Russia, for example the space launch site in Kazakhstan (Baikonur), and the naval base in Ukraine (Sevastopol).

Added remark. There was no such thing as a "corporation" in Soviet Union. There were plants (factories), and "manufacturing unions" which combined
several plants or factories. A plant or a union was immediately controlled by its director. The main goal of a plant or a union was not making profit, but fulfilling the "state plan". These plans were designed by the Federal or republican Gosplan. Other governance was performed by the federal or republican ministries.
The planners decided how many of widgets of each kind have to me made,
and where, and a special government committee in Moscow called [Goskomcen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Committee_on_Prices) established prices for them.

Comment: What about something like the outer space rocket launching thing in Kazakhstan? I'm given to understand that it's Russian, even to this day.

Comment: This place (Baikonur) was subject to special negotiations. Kazakhstan has no space industry of its own, so it could not use the testing site. It is owned by Kazakhstan but leased to Russia. Same happened to the naval base in Crimea. It was a subject of negotiations, and part of it was leased to Russia, to host Russia'a Black sea fleet, though it remains Ukrainian territory.

Comment: @Alex can you please provide some references about the Gospaln if possible? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Schwarz Kugelblitz: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosplan, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DerzhPlan, of course Russian and Ukrainian Wikipedias contain much more.

Comment: @Alex same thing happened to Soviet nukes in Ukraine, which Ukrainian politicians gave up in exchange for a piece of paper promising not to invade them...

Comment: JonathanReez: Already Bismarck said that "treaties with Russia are not worth the price paper on which they are written". What is really disturbing that this particular agreement was co-signed by the US and UK.

Comment: @Alex I'm guessing that the US and UK didn't want Ukraine to have nukes.

Comment: @kick012000: Yes, this part is clear. So they signed an obligation, jointly with Russia to "guarantee territorial integrity of Ukraine". And how did they protect it?

Comment: @Alex Russia got sanctions. The Rouble halved after the Crimea adventure. On the other hand, I think Russia and Ukraine never got to negotiating the border placement anyway.

Comment: @fraxinus: Sanctions do not have much effect. And about negotiating the border placement I did not understand: Ukraine's borders were established in 1990, and everyone recognized them, including Russia. So they are not subject of negotiations anymore.